# How to wait until datas are loaded?

Tags: flutter

I try to learn flutter and i face an issue with data loading.
I get information from sqlite database to display them in my homepage.
When starting my app, i have an error :
LateInitializationError: Field 'child' has not been initialized.

```
  late MonneyServices monneyServices;
  late ChildDAO childDAO;
  late Child child;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.monneyServices = MonneyServices();
      monneyServices.getChild().then((Child child) {
      this.child = child;
      setState(() {});
    });
```

the getChild method is async

```
  Future<Child> getChild() async {
    //return Child(1, 'Alice2', 100);
    Child child = Child(1, 'A', 1);

    this.childDAO.insertChild(Child(1, "Alice", 10));
    List<Child> childList = await this.childDAO.getChilds();
    child = childList.first;
    print(childList.first);

    return child;
  }
```

I use so datas in
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context)

How can i wait until datas are loaded ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: you can make the Object as nullable like Child? child and in just have an if check as in if(child != null) //here you can show your results

Comment: try to use the future builder , it will await until your widget is ready and you can provide a backup widget while the main one is loading.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

It lets you to await for a future to complete and return a different widget according to the future status.

In your case you should use it in the `build` method and not in `initState`.
You should use it more or less like so:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Widget>(context, snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData){ //If the future has completed
            return snapshot.data; //You return the widget it completed to
        } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator(); //Otherwise, return a progress indicator
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a boolean variable be sure the data is loaded and reflect this in the build

```
late MonneyServices monneyServices;
  late ChildDAO childDAO;
  late Child child;
  bool isLoading = true; // <--

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.monneyServices = MonneyServices();
      monneyServices.getChild().then((Child child) {
      this.child = child;
      isLoading = false; // <--
      setState(() {});
    });
```

and in the build:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if(isLoading) {
    return Text('loading...');
  }
  return child;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback !
Why do you say to avoid using this in state class ?

Comment: @Aurelien my bad , at the first glance i thought you have one "child" variable , i dont notice that you are use the same var name inside "monneyServices.getChild" callback